# How to call a function on body load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, socialshare

Hi I am using this script to add social media icon into my site.

```
<div id="menu" class="shareSelector" style="width:250px; height:250px;"></div>

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.shareSelector').socialShare({
        social: 'facebook,google,pinterest,twitter',
        whenSelect: true,
        selectContainer: '.shareSelector'
    });

});
```

div gets the content upon clicking on it.Can we call this function without clicking div means on bodyload?

Regards:Ali

Comment: seems like this will need to involve editing the `socialShare` plugin

Answer (score 3):

The `$(document).ready(function () {});` function should run when the page loads.

Have you got the jquery in a `<script>` tag?

If so, the bindings are setup by the socialShare plugin, so you may need to look at that.

What does whenSelect option do?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.shareSelector').socialShare({
    social: 'facebook,google,pinterest,twitter',
    whenSelect: true,
    selectContainer: '.shareSelector'
});
$('.shareSelector').click()  
});
```

Dont know about the socialShare plugin but you have an option there which says "whenSelect: true"

try false

Comment: Hi deach, I tried with both of your options but unfortunately They are not working.Thanks for your response.